# Admob Banner Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, swift3, admob

I'm trying to add a admob banner in a swift 3.0 file. My project is a combination of objc and swift 3.0 but I'm running into issues.

1. I can't add the GADBannerViewDelegate. I get about 20 errors about previous declaration of GADAdSize, GADGender, kGADGenderUnknown.
2. If I can't add the GADBannerViewDelegate then I can't set delegate = self
3. I get the following error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Here's my code:

```
func initAdMobBanner() {

    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        // iPhone
        //adBannerView.adSize =  GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: 320, height: 50))
        //adBannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.size.height, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 50)
    } else  {
        // iPad
        //adBannerView.adSize =  GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: 468, height: 60))
        //adBannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.size.height, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 60)
    }

    adBannerView.adUnitID = kadmobID
    adBannerView.rootViewController = self
    adBannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
    adBannerView.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(adBannerView)

    let request = GADRequest()
    adBannerView.load(request)
}


// Hide the banner
func hideBanner(_ banner: UIView) {
    UIView.beginAnimations("hideBanner", context: nil)
    banner.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.size.width/2 - banner.frame.size.width/2, y: view.frame.size.height - banner.frame.size.height, width: banner.frame.size.width, height: banner.frame.size.height)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
    banner.isHidden = true
}

// Show the banner
func showBanner(_ banner: UIView) {
    UIView.beginAnimations("showBanner", context: nil)
    banner.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.size.width/2 - banner.frame.size.width/2, y: view.frame.size.height - banner.frame.size.height, width: banner.frame.size.width, height: banner.frame.size.height)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
    banner.isHidden = false
}

// AdMob banner available
func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView!) {
    showBanner(adBannerView)
}

// NO AdMob banner available
func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError!) {
    hideBanner(adBannerView)
    print("adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: \(error.localizedDescription)")

}
```

**EDIT**

ok, so i've striped everything out except the 3 lines of code by in the google example and I get the following error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. I'm ruining the Google example and they don't have this issue which is weird. I don't have GADBannerViewDelegate because the google example doesn't have it either.

```
@IBOutlet weak var adBannerView: GADBannerView!
adBannerView.adUnitID = kadmobID
adBannerView.rootViewController = self
adBannerView.load(GADRequest())
```

Comment: you need to add all methods from protocol [GADBannerViewDelegate](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/ios/api/reference/Protocols/GADBannerViewDelegate)

Comment: No you don't @muescha, all of them are optional and it works just fine without adding any one of them

Comment: ok - then we need a list of "I get about 20 errors"